# Maximum size of call stack keeps varying in clojure

Tags: clojure, jvm

We wanted to check the max depth of the call stack on JVM, for that we ran the following

```
(defn abcd [i]
  "A function to find the max recursion allowed"
  (try (abcd (inc i))
     (catch Throwable t
       (println "Failed at" i)
       (prn (class t)))))
```

I expected the value of `i` to be same all the time because well the stack size is always going to be the same! (would be ok with small differences but here I saw the depth varying a lot)

```
(abcd 0)
Failed at 4852
java.lang.StackOverflowError

(abcd 0)
Failed at 4917
java.lang.StackOverflowError

(abcd 0)
Failed at 23609
java.lang.StackOverflowError

(abcd 0)
Failed at 23620
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

The depth was lesser in the first run and then was consistently at the 20k range. What optimisation would JVM be doing here?

Comment: JIT compilation. Compiler frames are smaller than interpreter frames. See the linked questions.